# Calling the appropriate methods for a given command

Tags: c++, command-prompt

I am making a command prompt in C++. I would like a user to enter a line such as "say something". This will then be split up so that "say" would be the command name and "something" would be a parameter. So far, so good - this is already working.

I would then like to use the name of the command to call the appropriate method. I could use some kind of look-up table but is there a better method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably you need something like map of command keywords and function or method pointers

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

class CmdHandler // our handler class
{
public:
    void Handler(const std::string &arg){}//our handler method
};


typedef void (CmdHandler::*MethodPtr)(const std::string &); // make typedef to easily deal with the type of the member-function pointer

std::map<std::string, MethodPtr> my_handlers; // make our method lookup table

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CmdHandler handler;
    //add a real member-function pointer for the "say" command
    my_handlers.insert(std::make_pair("say", &CmdHandler::Handler));

    //look for the handler of command "say" and call it instantly 
    (handler.*my_handlers["say"])("something");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could explain what exactly is happening in your code?

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't support any kind of reflection: some sort of table mapping names to function objects is the best approach I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

A look up table is the usual method. Usually, a [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)...and if you're using boost, you might want to look at [`boost::function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/function.html) and [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/bind/bind.html).

Also note that you might find the compiler macro [`__FUNCTION__`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (which expands to the undecorated name of the current function at compile time, and is often used in error messages - you might have to strip class names from member function names) useful in command functions, in order register functions in your map so that you can avoid misspellings and extra typing.

(Note that [`BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/current_function.hpp) might be a more portable macro.)